# Java native methods could not be resolved in eclipse, Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have imported the `ndk` sample project(`HelloJni`) into eclipse; it runs fine.

But when I try to open and edit the `C` `class`(hello) then it shows errors (`Method could not be resolved`) on `native methods`(like `jstring, JNIEnv, jobject`).

I have searched a lot on Google but I didn't find any answer that can help me out.

Please give some suggestions for fixing this error.

Comment: please accept the answer if you are satisfied with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution

Go to the properties of your Application , under `C/C++ General -->Code Analysis`

`Uncheck the Run As You Type (Selected Checkers)` option as following screenshot.

[image]